# .NET Create struct property getter delegate

Tags: c#

I have method that create property getter delegate:

```
private static Delegate CreatePropertyGetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        MethodInfo propertyGetter = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();

        DynamicMethod dynGetter = new DynamicMethod
                                  (
                                      String.Concat("DM$MEMBER_GETTER_", propertyInfo.Name),
                                      propertyInfo.PropertyType,
                                      new Type[1] { propertyInfo.DeclaringType },
                                      propertyInfo.DeclaringType,
                                      true
                                  );

        ILGenerator ilGen = dynGetter.GetILGenerator();

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

        ilGen.EmitCall(propertyInfo.DeclaringType.IsValueType ? OpCodes.Call : OpCodes.Callvirt, propertyGetter, null);

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return dynGetter.CreateDelegate(typeof(MemberGetter<,>).MakeGenericType(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
    }
```

This code work fine with classes, but structs throw ArgumentNullException when i try get property value.

Comment: Why don't you simply call [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) instead of messing with IL? Additionally, it'll be much faster.

Comment: Is there an inner exception? What is the definition of MemberGetter? Is there a reason you use that instead of just Func<,>? How are you invoking the created delegate? Are you passing in an instance?

Comment: Lucas, please show example that will be faster code above.

Comment: @KozilovMichael: first line, then `return CreateDelegate(typeof(MemberGetter<,>).MakeGenericType(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, propertyInfo.PropertyType), propertyGetter);`  Or get rid of `MemberGetter` and use `Func` or `Converter` that .NET provides for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing a line from this:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
```

to this:

```
ilGen.Emit(propertyInfo.DeclaringType.IsValueType ? OpCodes.Ldarga : OpCodes.Ldarg, 0);
```

This loads the address of the first argument (located on the stack), which is required for calling instance methods on structures.
However, I'd prefer using System.Linq.Expressions instead of Emit.

Answer (score 0):

When [calling a method on a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075167/calling-methods-on-value-types) you must provide a managed pointer to that struct on the IL evaluation stack. Right now you are loading the struct itself which is incorrect.

You need to throw this away. Better use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to obtain a delegate to the getter method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on a few things about this.  You are making a generic delegate but then just returning Delegate.  Will you invoke this using DynamicInvoke or how should that work?  If you can cast it then you already knew the type info so the efficacy of something dynamic like this seems greatly reduced.  Also, you don't seem to be unboxing the return value.  If that's a value type it's going to cause problems.  If it were me I'd do it more like this

```
public static PropValDelegate CreatePropertyGetter<TIn>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, TIn ownerObj)
    {
        MethodInfo propertyGetter = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();

        DynamicMethod dynGetter = new DynamicMethod
        (
            String.Empty, typeof(object), new Type[1] {typeof(TIn)},
            propertyInfo.DeclaringType, true
        );

        ILGenerator ilGen = dynGetter.GetILGenerator();
        ilGen.Emit(propertyInfo.DeclaringType.IsValueType ? OpCodes.Ldarga : OpCodes.Ldarg, 0);
        ilGen.EmitCall(propertyInfo.DeclaringType.IsValueType ? OpCodes.Call : OpCodes.Callvirt, propertyGetter, null);

        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType)
        {
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Box, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        }

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (lambdaObject) => (PropValDelegate<TIn>)dynGetter.CreateDelegate(typeof(PropValDelegate<TIn>));
    }
```

where we have a generic and non-generic version of the delegate but each accepts an object input so we can do early bound invocation and caching more easily with the harpiness of generics